# Python Flask SQLAlchemy-Paginator Access next page in html view

Tags: python, html, pagination, sqlalchemy

I have currently a problem to include the pagination function into my project. I know there is `LIMIT/OFFSET`or `yield_per()`, but I was not able to implement them.

I am using SQLAlchemy not Flask-SQLAlchemy so `paginate` wont work.

My Database is not that big. I am trying to show rooms which have been added by a user. So all in all a user will have 20~ rooms, big users maybe 100. I want to show on the profile page the 6 last inserted rooms and if there are more, there should be pagination, like page 2 shows the next 6 etc.

I am using [SQLAlchemy-Paginator](https://github.com/ahmadjavedse/sqlalchemy-paginator).

I already implemented it and tested it, it works fine. It also limits already the results depending on which page I am. But how do I access the next page while on HTML?

Here is the python code:

```
@app.route("/user/logged_in")
@login_required
@check_confirmed
def logged_in():
    if current_user.email_verified:
        users_room = db_session.query(Zimmer).filter_by(users_id=current_user.id).order_by(desc("id"))
        paginator = Paginator(users_room, 2)
        for page in paginator:
            print "page number of current page in iterator", page.number
            print "this is a list that contains the records of current page", page.object_list      
        return render_template('logged_in.html', paginator=paginator)
    return redirect(url_for('unconfirmed'))
```

Here is the view. The solution must be somewhere here. I can access pages by `page.previous_page_number` or `page.next_page_number`. But there is no example in the docu how to do it in view.

```
<div class="user-rooms">
<h2> Ihre Zimmer </h2>
{% for page in paginator %} 
{% if page.number == 1 % }
{% for zimmer in page.object_list %} 
{% if zimmer.users_id == current_user.id %}
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 img-holder">
<img src="../static/userimg/{{ zimmer.hauptbild }}"/>
<div class="buttons-del-work"> <a href="{{ url_for('edit_room', the_room_id=zimmer.id) }}" class="btn mybtn-work"> Bearbeiten </a> <a href="{{ url_for('delete_room', the_room_id=zimmer.id) }}" class="btn mybtn-del"> Löschen </a>  </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If I manually change the page numbers here it show me the correct items, so I feel like I am close:

```
{% if page.number == 1 % }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is a solution (which does not use any further methods from the SQLAlchemy-Paginator package). I coded everything myself, but I would still like to know how it is done with `page.next_page_number` etc.

**Explained:**

First of all I added an argument (`pagenumber`) to my `logged_in` function. Everytime `url_for("logged_in", pagenumber=1)` is called the pagenumber has to be set to the defaultvalue `1`.

I created an empty list, where I add all the `page.number` items, so I know how many pages my resultset will have:

```
pages_list = []
    for page in paginator:
        pages_list.append(page.number)
```

I use the `pages_list` also in the view to generate the buttons which can be clicked to see the next page, I also give the `pagenumber` to the html view:

```
return render_template('logged_in.html', paginator=paginator, pagenumber=pagenumber, pages_list=pages_list)
```

Here is the HTML view where I show the buttons:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
{% for number in pages_list %} 
<a href="{{ url_for('logged_in', pagenumber = number) }}"> {{ number }} </a>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Now if a user clicks one of the Buttons the `logged_in` will be called with a new pagenumber argument (the actual pagesite you clicked)

In the logged_in I added also typecasted pagenumber to int before giving it to html view:

```
pagenumber = int(pagenumber)
```

**Solution Code**

Python:

```
def logged_in(pagenumber):
if current_user.email_verified:

    users_room = db_session.query(Zimmer).filter_by(users_id=current_user.id).order_by(desc("id"))

    paginator = Paginator(users_room, 2)
    pages_list = []
    for page in paginator:
        pages_list.append(page.number)

    pagenumber = int(pagenumber)

    return render_template('logged_in.html', paginator=paginator, pagenumber=pagenumber, pages_list=pages_list)
return redirect(url_for('unconfirmed'))
```

HTML:

```
<div class="user-rooms">
<h2> Ihre Zimmer </h2>
{% for page in paginator %} 
{% if page.number == pagenumber %}
{% for zimmer in page.object_list %} 
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 img-holder">
<img src="../static/userimg/{{ zimmer.hauptbild }}"/>
<div class="buttons-del-work"> <a href="{{ url_for('edit_room', the_room_id=zimmer.id) }}" class="btn mybtn-work"> Bearbeiten </a> <a href="{{ url_for('delete_room', the_room_id=zimmer.id) }}" class="btn mybtn-del"> Löschen </a>  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12">
{% for number in pages_list %} 
<a href="{{ url_for('logged_in', pagenumber = number) }}"> {{ number }} </a>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```